# What materials/information would I need to construct a gameworld?

Tags: world-building

I'm planning on creating my own game world and I was wondering what specifics should I be looking at to help with its accuracy, detail and playability?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately I believe this question is far to broad to be answerable on this site. You could write an entire book on this subject. One thing you could consider in trying to narrow it down is to give more details as to the genre, system and any other requirements you know you have. I have voted to put the question on hold, and if enough others agree, this will stop people answering the question until it has been sufficiently edited.

Comment: There is also a World-Building tag, which has 61 questions associated with it. You should have a look through those and see if their answers have any information that answers your question

Comment: There's also a [WorldBuilding.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding?referrer=CNfo5J7BJM6wPEcXjUoAHg2) proposal on Area51 you might be interested in.

Comment: I see you have the rules-as-written tag, but have not mentioned *which* rules.